# Why does the infinitesimal of a poisson process behave as it does in the Ito multiplication table

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, poisson-process, levy-processes

In more informal derivations of Ito's formula for jump processes, the multiplication table for $dt, dW_t$ and $dN_t$give that $dN_tdN_t=dN_t$. Why is this? I have tried deriving this from the telescoping sums arising from jump process integration but I can't get much traction